# How can I check $username to UserName from a database using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO and PHP to write information to a database. I want to check if $tblusername (which is the username the user puts in) is the same as anything in the column UserName in my database. UserName is under tblUsers. Here's my existing code:

```
try {
        $tblusername = $_POST['Username'];
        $tblemail = $_POST['Email'];
        $tblpassword = $_POST['Password'];

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mealplan", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers");

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        die("Username already in use!");
        }else{
          echo "3";
          $sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUsers` (`UserName`, `Email`, `UserPassword`) VALUES ('?', '?', '?')";
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)->execute([$tblusername, $tblemail, $tblpassword]);
        }

      } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "<style>.hidden { visibility: visible; } .shown { visibility: hidden; font-size: 0px }</style>";
      }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you are doing things wrong first you should select from the table Where Username = $tblusername

Comment: so "SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers WHERE UserName = $tblUsername"?

Comment: @TheDarkGamer Never put variables in SQL. Your insert has an error, don't quote placeholders.

Comment: user3783243 Yes, I figured that out after I did the other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP PDO you are required to pass the UserName parameter for `where` clause condition using `bindParam` so that it will help to fetch unique row for given `UserName`. You can follow the given code.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers where UserName=:tblusername");
$stmt->bindParam(':tblusername', $tblusername);   
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed It! Needed to add WHERE UserName = $tblUsername and remove the '?' and replace it with just the ?.